# Flatten nested json with many column types( some nested)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am pulling from an API where the output looks like the below (tried to make it as formatted as possible):

```
{
    "other":{
                Not important.. (ignored later)
            },
    "resultList":[
        {
            "date": "2017-10-26T21:52:59.840Z",
            "uniqueId": "c0a9c665-0f6f-c8",
            "children":[
                {
                    "identifier": "FAMR@316069707@3160697070",
                    "score": 1,
                    "parentId": "c0a9c665-0f6f-4fc8"
                },
                {
                    Same format as first child...
                },
                {
                    Same format as first child...
                }
            ],
            "weights":[
                60,
                20,
                20
            ],
            "type": "ABC"
        },
        {
            Same format as first dictionary…
        }
    ]
}
```

As per searches on stackoverflow, I tackled it by extracting the json, normalizing its output only for `resultList` (that's the only piece I care about), and then orienting it by column and converting to Pandas DataFrame. 
This is the code:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd 
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

# Get JSON from API
user = str(input("Enter User Name: ")) 
password = getpass.getpass("Enter Password: ") 
url = 'https://API_url'
req = requests.post(url = url, auth=(user, password))
out = req.json()

# Create normalized dataframe from API
solr_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(json_normalize(out["resultList"]), orient='columns')
```

However, while this flattens `resultList` into columns, the `children` column remains nested as list of dictionaries (Actually with `u` appended to it, which I don't want) and `weights` column remains a list..

Can you please assist in restructuring this to return a result where both children and weights are flattened as columns?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions. Thanks!

Comment: You're referring to the @ parsing addition? Sorry removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't think of a more efficient way to do this, although I'm sure one exists.

Looped through the json object and manually flattened the data.

```
dfAll = pd.DataFrame()
for record in r['resultList']:

    conc = []
    otherFields = {}

    for field in record:

        if isinstance(record[field], list):
            if len(record[field]) > 0:
                if isinstance(record[field][0], dict):
                    conc.append(pd.DataFrame(record[field]))

                else:
                    conc.append(pd.DataFrame(record[field],columns=[field]))

        else:
            otherFields[field] = record[field]


    df = pd.concat(conc,axis=1)

    for field in otherFields:
        df[field] = otherFields[field]

    dfAll = dfAll.append(df)

dfAll


   weights                 identifier            parentId  score  \
0       60  FAMR@316069707@3160697070  c0a9c665-0f6f-4fc8      1   
1       20  FAMR@316069707@3160697070  c0a9c665-0f6f-4fc8      1   
2       20  FAMR@316069707@3160697070  c0a9c665-0f6f-4fc8      1   
0       10  FAMR@316069707@3160697070  c0a9c665-0f6f-4fc8      1   
1       20  FAMR@316069707@3160697070  c0a9c665-0f6f-4fc8      1   
2       30  FAMR@316069707@3160697070  c0a9c665-0f6f-4fc8      1   

                       date type          uniqueId  
0  2017-10-26T21:52:59.840Z  ABC  c0a9c665-0f6f-c8  
1  2017-10-26T21:52:59.840Z  ABC  c0a9c665-0f6f-c8  
2  2017-10-26T21:52:59.840Z  ABC  c0a9c665-0f6f-c8  
0  2015-10-26T21:52:59.840Z  ABC               123  
1  2015-10-26T21:52:59.840Z  ABC               123  
2  2015-10-26T21:52:59.840Z  ABC               123
```

Comment: Nathan thank you for your answer. Unfortunately I have ALOT of columns, I just showed the relevant ones, and a few others. So manually doing  df['column'] = record['column'] will have to be done to 20+ columns

Comment: please see my edited answer for a more dynamic way to do it.

Comment: Hmm. Thank you for the edited response.
For: "if isinstance(record[field][0], dict):",
I am getting an error of: "IndexError: list index out of range"

Comment: see edited again - there must be sum empty lists there

Comment: Sorry, df[field] = otherFields[field] seems to raise ValueError('Length of values does not match length of ' 'index'). By the way is it normal that there are 3 if statements, but only 2 else statements?

Comment: That is fine (3 if and 2 else), however could you add `print(field, otherFields[field])` before df[field] = ? so we can debug this

Comment: Do you mean like this: for field in otherFields:
        print(field, otherFields[field])
        df[field] = otherFields[field]? If so this is what it printed:
(u'origin', u'mw')
(u'parentFlag', True)
(u'UserId', u'toconnor')
(u'defaultPositionsFlag', False)
(u'description', u'Gains 2017')
(u'dateLastModified', u'2017-10-27T17:55:10.920Z')
(u'dates', {u'mwLastModified': u'2017-10-27T17:55:07.379Z'})

Comment: Yes, please let me know which field is giving the error

Comment: It was dates column, I extracted its result in the back end (it was either null or dictionary, hence the error), and the query runs perfectly. Thank you!